# Is it gramatically correct to start a new sentence with Moreover without the comma?

Tags: commas, translation

I'm translating a book, and the following bolded sentence came up in a bit of dialogue, shown translated below.

“…He is a lone traveler, and possibly a minor. **Moreover he is Japanese.** That country of mass media is certain to be a bother.”

The original text for the bolded "Moreover he is Japanese" is below, for comparison purposes.

しかも日本人。

I know that in English, Moreover is used to connect two senteces together with a semi-colon and comma, or is used at the start of a new sentence with a comma. I'm wondering if its possible to leave out the comma, and still be correct for American English.

Comment: It will be grammatically correct no matter how many commas you put in because just like spelling and capitalization **commas are mere matters of orthography not of grammar.**  If a native speaker who is both blind and illiterate wouldn’t notice if it’s said to him aloud then it’s not grammar. You don't mean “grammatically correct” because that would be about the language's syntax and morphology. You perhaps mean would it be “orthographically correct” because that would only be about writing something down in some expected or acceptable fashion according to some publishing house or style guide.

Comment: @tchrist I didn't know the word "orthography" existed before you mentioned it, thanks for the advice!

Comment: _Moreover_ isn't really used much in spoken English. You'd be better off with _also_.

Comment: (British Eng. here!) I disagree with @KarlG that "also" would be suitable because the text conveys a key issue - not just a supplementary comment. In **spoken** British English, one might say, "What's more, he's Japanese."  But, personally, I don't see any issue with "Moreover".

Comment: *Typically*, a comma goes after *moreover* because it [acts](https://onlinewritingtraining.com.au/2018/07/25/however-therefore-furthermore/) to introduce an independent clause. (The link points to an article that confirms your reasoning.) It's not actually wrong to leave out the comma, but, at least stylistically, it would be included more often than not. If I were editing your sentence (barring a style guide that said otherwise), I would insert one; if I were proofreading it, I would not.